# executing javascript securily on Android without a webview

Tags: javascript, android, http, security, https

My aim is to run a JavaScript that will trigger some http request. It's crucial that the requests are executed in a secure way (https, cert pinning etc.). No UI will be shown to a user, pure background job. Normally a webview does the job for free and would be a fallback. A size of the webview could be 0x0dp, but maybe there's a less obscure way to achieve it. I've been searching for a solution that would allow me to run JavaScript with https requests but without success yet. Any help/hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why JavaScript? Easily in java: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#HttpsExample

Comment: I have to do it in JavaScript for some reasons :|

Comment: Short answer: JavaScript needs an environment to run in --> HTML --> WebView